# Or operator on angularjs filter

Tags: angularjs

i'm trying to get 2 object of a table.

```
var tab=[
{t:"t1",selected:true},
{t:"t2"},
{t:"t3",selected:false}];
```

Where selected is false or undefined.

With `$filter('filter')(tab,{selected:"!"}||{selected:false});`

I only get the object `[{"t":"t2"}]`

Is it possible to filter with an or operator with this filter?

Comment: Why don't you just do it before the filter and then pass it in?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create [your own filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters) for it:

```
.filter('myfilter', function() {
  return function(selected) {
    return selected === '!' || selected === false;
  };
});
```